# Microdata showing empty itemscope and false values for itemref

Tags: 7

I have installed [Microdata](https://www.drupal.org/project/microdata) 7.x-1.0-beta2 module, I am facing few issues in my structured data. I added all the fields in my content type for Microdata, but when I am viewing the source of my page it's showing the following lines:

```html
</div><span itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/NewsArticle" itemid="http://beta.siteaddress.com/news/interest-building-construction" itemref="md1 md2 md3 md4" ></span>
```

I am not sure why it's showing the `itemscope` field blank and `itemref` fields as `md1,md2,md3,md4`.

What I am expecting it should show me the `itemprop` for my two image fields, because I have two image fields in my content type.

Please report if anyone is facing the same issue, and if anyone had fixed it please let me know how to get rid of this.

Comment: Does the element with `id="md1"` have an `itemprop` attribute?

Comment: Voting to close because this reads like a bug report and there's no explicit question asked here.